# JSF How to display string value retrieved from session?

Tags: session, jsf

I can not display the value of a String attribute of an object stored in sessionMap: `<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.myObject.stringField}" />`.
It also does not work when I assign a value of a String variable to a key in the session map.
It only works when I assign a String literal value to a key.

---

Example:

*test.xhtml*

Outputs s1 to s3 show class name + hash code.
Outputs s4 to s9 display nothing.
Output s10 displays the word "test".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty usuarioLogado}"
        value=" 
        s1 #{usuarioLogado}
        s2 #{sessionScope.usuarioLogado}
        s3 #{sessionScope['usuarioLogado']}
        s4 #{usuarioLogado.nome}
        s5 #{sessionScope.usuarioLogado.nome}
        s6 #{sessionScope['usuarioLogado'].nome}
        s7 #{nomeUsuarioLogado}
        s8 #{sessionScope.nomeUsuarioLogado}            
        s9 #{sessionScope['nomeusuarioLogado'].nome}
        s10 #{sessionScope.string_literal} ">
    </h:outputText>

</h:body>
</html>
```

*LoginBean.java*

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private Usuario usuario;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public LoginBean() {

    }

    //getters and setters

    public String efetuarLogin(){

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        boolean existeUsuario = new UsuarioDao(em).consultarUsuario(usuario);
        em.close();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (existeUsuario) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuarioLogado", this.usuario);
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("nomeUsuarioLogado", this.usuario.getNome());
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("string_literal", "test");

            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

*Usuario.java*

```
public class Usuario {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String email;

    public Usuario() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Your English is very good

Comment: I maybe miss something obvious, but I'd initially say: s1 to s3: is logical, you did not implement a 'toString()' in your object. s4 to s9: then 'nome'  is most likely empty in your object.

Comment: @Kukeltje I did not mention it, but "nome" is a required field. There is an earlier validation step so that "nome" is never empty. tks

Comment: I thougt it was a casting problem but I realized now you already put String in the map with "nomeUsuarioLogado" key. So nome can be empty.

Comment: If some getters/setters are called before this, make sure those kinds of **very relevant** things are visible in your code. Now I have been investigating code that is not the code that runs. Does it work if you assign values statically to your Usario bean? If so, getting the values FROM the (session) bean works and getting them TO the bean does not! (s10 works, so I tend to think your problem is **setting** the values. Create a [mcve]!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my fault. A very elemental logic error. All of you were right: the "nome" attribute was empty.
I should have informed here the source code of the xhtml login page where I captured the data for my "LoginBean.Usuario". On this page, there is a form for entering the values "Usuario.login" and "Usuario.senha". So I used these values as criteria for searching "Usuario" in the database, but the method returned only a boolean, not the entity "Usuario" found in the database.
Therefore, the solution was to change the search method in the database (in UsuarioDao class), so that it returned a "Usuario" object (or null), and assigns it to the "LoginBean.usuario" field.

*LoginBean* now looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private Usuario usuario;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public LoginBean() {

    }

    //getters and setters

    public String efetuarLogin(){

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        // now a Usuario is returned, in which the "nome" attribute is filled.
        this.usuario = new UsuarioDao(em).consultarUsuario(this.usuario);
        em.close();  

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (existeUsuario) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuarioLogado", this.usuario);

            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Weird... you stated:  _"@Kukeltje I did not mention it, but "nome" is a required field. There is an earlier validation step so that "nome" is never empty. tks – "_ So that was not true. Otherwise it would have been populated!

Comment: @Kukeltje You're right. Sorry about that.
In fact, nome is a required field when a new Usuario is registered. There is a validation in the Usuario registration form that requires "nome". So, in the database, there isn't Usuario with no nome.
However, in the login page, only the "login" and "senha" fields are entered. So my "LoginBean.usuario" had "nome" empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bean method like this:

```
public Usuario giveMeTheValue(String key){
return (Usuario) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(key);
}
```

And in xhtml:

```
s6 #{bean.giveMeTheValue('usuarioLogado').nome}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try the solution you proposed later and then I'll come back here to report the result.